# No WLAN connection for one Xiaomi MiA2 mobile phone?

Tags: wi-fi, router

We bought some days ago a new WLan Router (FRITZ!Box 7530). Everything went fine, only one single mobile doesn't connect properly. We reseted all settings of this phone to (Xiaomi MiA2), tried to connect - didn't work.

We switched on and off the power of the mobile and the router several times. Chose "delete network" at the mobile and wrote the password again. No change.
Furthermore, and that's really weird: If we build a WLAN bridge from another mobile, then *this* WLAN connection works with the Xiaomi. Therefore, the WLAN ability of this phone is not broken. Seems to be only something wrong with the settings.

How can we connect this mobile to our network?

Addendum:

When we try to connect it shows "connection saved" ("gespeichert" in German). But no connection is established. The mobile doesn't appears in the Connection list of the Router.

What security method does the new Wi-Fi use (WPA2, WPA3, etc.) and to your knowledge is the phone compatible with that security method?
I *think* it's WPA2

What version of Android is the phone running (is it up-to-date on its security updates, etc.)?
Android 10. No Updates available (2021)

Comment: "didn't work" as in (1) never attempted to connect, (2) showed an error whilst connecting (if so, what error?), or (3) showed it was connected but did not seem to have a connection? What security method does the new Wi-Fi use (WPA2, WPA3, etc.) and to your knowledge is the phone compatible with that security method? What version of Android is the phone running (is it up-to-date on its security updates, etc.)?

Comment: [Lot of wifi related problems, factory-reset, changing time/day seems to have worked for some](https://support.google.com/android/thread/37744848/after-last-android-update-xiaomi-mi-a2-having-wifi-problems?hl=en) //From personal experience, don't expect any help from OEM//searching in MI forums is another option

Comment: Thank you @Sam Forbes, I tried to add in the question

Answer (score 1):

I would try with to connect with other WIFI security protocols/settings.
If your router supports multiple WIFI networks, you could try creating another network to test older security protocols without breaking the already set connections of other client devices.

Also could try WPS authentication.